# Check if char array[] contains int, float or double value and store value to respective data type

Tags: c

In C programming, how do i check whether `char array[]` contains `int`, `float` or `double` value and also store the value using respective data type?

Example:
If the `char array[]` contains `100` - its `int` value and should be store in `int a`.
 if the char array contains `10000.01` its `float` value and should be stored in `float b`.

Comment: By `char` array, do you mean an array of strings?

Comment: if we consider 1000.01 the value stored in array is as follows array[0]=1, array[1]=0,array[2]=0,array[3]=0,array[4]=. ,array[5]=0 and array[6]=1

Comment: Are you trying to convert a C string into a number? If so, you should make your question clearer. Many of the current answers misunderstand your intentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can store mixed types in an array is to have an array of pointers.

You'd need to use a struct or a union to store each one too like so:

```
#define TYPE_INT 1
#define TYPE_FLOAT 2
#define TYPE_STRING 3

typedef struct  {
  int type;
  void *ptr;
} object;

object* mkobject( int type, void * data ){
  object * obj = (object*)malloc(COUNT*sizeof(object))
  obj->type = type;
  obj->ptr = data;
  return obj;
}
```

No using the above you can store type information

```
void * intdup( int original ) {
  int * copy = (int*) malloc(1*sizeof(int));
  *copy = original; 
  return (void*) copy;
}

void * floatdup( float original ) {
  float * copy = (float*) malloc(1*sizeof(float));
  *copy = original; 
  return (void*) copy;
}

int COUNT = 3;
objects** objectlist = (object**)malloc(COUNT*sizeof(object*))

// -- add things to the list
int a_number = 2243;
float a_float = 1.24;
char* a_string = "hello world"; 


objectlist[0] = mkobject( TYPE_STRING, strdup(a_string) );
objectlist[1] = mkobject( TYPE_INT, intdup(a_number) );
objectlist[2] = mkobject( TYPE_FLOAT, intdup(a_float) );


// iterate through a list

for ( int x = 0; x < COUNT; x++ ){

   switch( objectlist[x]->type ){

      case TYPE_STRING:
       printf("string [%s]\n",(char*) objectlist[x]->ptr );
       break;
      case TYPE_FLOAT:
       printf("float  [%f]\n", *(float*) objectlist[x]->ptr );
       break;
      case TYPE_INT:
       printf("int    [%d]\n", *(int*) objectlist[x]->ptr );
       break;
      default;
       printf("unintialized object\n");
       break;

   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C, unlike in other languages, you have to define the type of the variable at compile time. So if you have a char variable (or char array), you have char and not int and not float and not double.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is not possible to define variables types at run-time, you would still need to have variables of the correct data type defined at compile time. If that is not a problem, you could probably scan the string and look for decimal separators to determine if it is a float or integer value. But perhaps not the most robust method :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use a [union](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/unions.html) (from my understanding of your answer).

```
union {
   char a[4];
   float b;
   int c;
} dude;
// ...
union dude woah;
woah.a = "abc";
puts(a);
woah.b = 4.3;
printf("%f\n", woah.b);
woah.c = 456;
printf("%d\n", woah.c);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing a value like:

```
"100.04"
```

in the char array or something like that you can do this to check if the number has a decimal or not:

```
double check = atof(theChar);

if (check % 1 > 0) {
    //It's a real number
}
else {
    //It's more specifically an integer
}
```

If that is what you mean. Your question is a little unclear to me.

Although, this isn't really type checking, it is just testing where the thing has a decimal or not... Like others have said you can't do it because the char* is defined during compilation not during run time and can't be change.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the number is a floating point number and use [`strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html).

If the conversion worked, the number can be integer. Check limits and closeness to a proper integer and convert again if ok.

Pseudo-code

```
char *input = "42.24";
char *err;
errno = 0;
double x = strtod(input, &err);
if (errno == 0) {
    /* it's (probably) a floating point value */
    if ((INT_MIN <= x) && (x <= INT_MAX)) {
        if (fabs(x - (int)x) < 0.00000001) {
            /* It's an integer */
            int i = x;
        }
    }
} else {
    /* deal with error */
}
```