# check the type of array

Tags: arrays, c

I have 2 arrays int and float,one is commented, I would like to check the type of these arrays if int it should send to fun1() otherwise to fun2():
How can  I check the type of array?

```
int arr[]={4,6,7,8};
//float arr[]={5.4,7.4,3.3,};

if (type == int)
   fun1(arr);
else if(type == float)
   fun2(arr);
else 
 printf("not");
```

Comment: Do you expect this to happen at runtime? What is the intended use?

Comment: Hi @IanNorton
 Can you help in some thing like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6502201/13128303   please ?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check the type of array?

You can use generic selection to choose which function to call based on the type of an expression.  Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun1 (int arr[]) {
    puts("My argument is an int pointer");
}

void fun2 (float arr[]) {
    puts("My argument is a float pointer");
}

int main() {
    // int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    float arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    _Generic(arr,
            int *   : fun1,
            float * : fun2)(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

That particular usage doesn't make much sense, as you *know* what the type is, and, therefore, which function to call.  The more usual use case is to use generic selection in a macro, so that it is reusable, and the name of the macro gives you information about what all the type-specific functions do.  Something like this:

```
#define fun(x) _Generic((x),      \
            int *   : fun1,       \
            float * : fun2)(x)

// ...

    fun(arr);

// ...
```

Comment: The problem is how to make arr would be either of the type int * or of the type float *.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, where appropriate, array-to-pointer conversion is applied to the controlling expression of a generic selection, so that's not a problem at all.  Try the example program presented.

Comment: I get on this error error: '_Generic' was not declared in this scope Why ?

Comment: @oleva, generic selection was introduced in C11 (latest is C17).  It sounds like your compiler does not support C11, or is running with its C11 support disabled.  You might be able to affect that via command-line arguments, but you should consider getting a newer / better compiler instead.

Comment: Is there any other solution or using some think like 
"String type = arr.getClass().getComponentType().toString();"  
I tried to find an alternative to it in C, but I couldn't find. :(

Comment: @oleva, the primary alternative is to simply use your knowledge of the actual type of the object to write the correct alternative.  That information is *always* available to you when you write the code, as this answer already discusses.  You could also consider engaging a macro-based approach that allows you to switch the object's type and the function to call *in concert*, though that's not what you actually asked.  C has no other kind of introspective feature than generic selection.

Answer (score -3):

I think thats what you are looking for...

```
int arr[]={4,6,7,8};
String type = arr.getClass().getComponentType().toString();
if (type == "int")
    fun1(arr);
else if(type == "float")
    fun2(arr);
else 
    printf("not");
```

Comment: Yes like this, but I get on this error (request for member 'getClass' in 'arr', which is of non-class type 'float [1154]' )  I used float type

Comment: This doesn't look like C.

Comment: @oleva It looks like you might be using a C++ compiler. C does not have classes. Note C and C++ are very different languages and the answer would be different for each one.

Comment: Yes I think in java ?!!